# Unable to Share Facebook Ad Pixel using Graph API - Error (#10)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I've been encountering an issue while attempting to share an Ad Dataset (Pixel) using the Graph API. Here are the pertinent details:

Endpoint Used: POST https://graph.facebook.com/v16.0/<PIXEL_ID>/shared_accounts
Parameters:
account_id: [AD_ACCOUNT_ID]
business: [BUSINESS_MANAGER_ID]
Access Token: I've ensured it's valid and has the necessary permissions
(ads_management and business_management).
However, each time I execute the request, I am met with the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#10) An error occurred",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 10,
    "fbtrace_id": "AnkD7-Q6rPQ79amusIuRmhP"
  }
}
```

Here are the steps and checks I've undertaken:

Verified the token's validity and permissions.
Double-checked all IDs used in the request.
Confirmed I'm sharing the correct asset (Pixel). Notably, the pixel I'm trying to share appears under the "Datasets" tab and not under the standard "Pixels" tab in Facebook Ads Manager.
I'd be incredibly grateful for any insights, guidance, or suggestions on the source of this error and potential resolutions.

Thank you in advance!